# Moment.js and ion rangeSlider: Date not formatted

Tags: javascript, slider, momentjs, rangeslider

I'm using an ion slider (http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html) and moment.js to handle dates. The problem is that the date does not get formatted the way it should on the slider.

```
var beginMoment = moment("2015-04-20");
var endMoment = moment("2015-08-20");

console.log("Begin");
console.log(beginMoment);

$("#chord_range").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "double",

    min: +moment(beginMoment).format("X"),
    max: +moment(endMoment).format("X"),

    from: +moment(beginMoment).format("X"),
    to: +moment(endMoment).format("X"),

    prettify: function (num) {
            return moment(num, "X").format("dddd, MMM Do YYYY");
    }});
```

The log does give the correct format however. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe "not get formatted the way it should"? How is it getting formatted?

Comment: On the slider it is just the unix timestamp. Not at all in any human-readable format.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem. [Check this fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/2a0hsj4z/).

Comment: I used the .min.js file in my project instead of the regular .js file like you do, when I change it it works just fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working. Weird that the .min file works, but the regular one doesn't. Wonder if they are different versions before the minification is applied.

Comment: Yeah, there's some weird things going on. With the regular file I don't get the dates but I do get the `irs-diapason` between the two sliders, where as when I use the .min file, I do get the dates, but not the diapason...

Comment: Check this demo playground with Ion.RangeSlider and Moment.js: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/w1ucb8bm/ try to reproduce your problem.